# Debian does't work ssh authorize key

Tags: debian, ssh, key-authentication

I have server access on Debian on my machine №1. 
Authorization is good.

I want to do the same on the machine №2. Generated keys, write public at the end `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. But I have an error message `Connection timed out`.

I take the same keys and do authorization on another server on Ubuntu. Write public at the end `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. And authorization is good.

What is my problem?

Comment: 2nd machine not reachable over the network? Maybe you used a wrong address or host name? Some firewall dropping packets? Please show the exact commands for the good and bad case in your question.

Comment: machine №1 
MacBook at home 
ssh name@adress -port   - good

machine №2
ubuntu at work
ssh name@adress -port   - bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Connection timed out" is not related to SSH keys at all.

It means the SSH client is not getting any answer from the remote server at all, so it cannot even get to the point where it would offer the key.

It is usually caused by firewalls, so check your `iptables` firewall settings. If you have external firewall devices, check their settings too.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know that can block out connection to port like 12345, but it is block